# How to insert opening div in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to insert an opening div but it closes itself automatically. How do I get this to work.

I want to wrap thses two divs in one div called controls...

```
<div class="carousel-prev prev-next"></div>
<div class="carousel-next prev-next"></div>
```

So I get...

```
<div id="controls">
<div class="carousel-prev"></div>
<div class="carousel-next"></div>
</div>
```

I did try:

```
$(".jcarousel-prev").before("<div id='controls'>");
```

But as I mentioned above, it closes automatically.

Comment: Can't you just get the contents of (I assume) '.jcarousel-prev' and replace it with `<div id='controls'> [contents] </div>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".prev-next").wrapAll("<div id='controls'>");
```

in your particular case you're removing class too i.e.

```
$(".prev-next").removeClass('prev-next').wrapAll("<div id='controls'>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/):

```
$(".prev-next).wrapAll('<div />');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use wrap function to achieve that:

http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: Actually, that would wrap each matched element separately. Use .wrapAll() instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
$(".prev-next").appendTo("<div id='controls'>");
```